# babel-node not recognizing jsx <

Tags: node.js, babeljs, reactjs

I am trying to run some code that uses `React` and `JSX` using `babel-node`, which is part of the [babel-cli](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/).  To the best of my knowledge the code is correct and I am using `babel-node` as expected, but hopefully someone can provide more insight.

The following error is generated.

```
(!535)-> babel-node server.js
/Users/eprouty/.nvm/versions/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:520
      throw err;
      ^

SyntaxError: /Users/ep/git/dgcastle/server.js: Unexpected token (60:51)
  58 |                 res.status(302).redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
  59 |             } else if (renderProps) {
> 60 |                 var html = ReactDOM.renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />);
     |                                                    ^
  61 |                 var page = jade.renderFile('views/index.jade', {html: html});
  62 |                 res.status(200).send(page);
  63 |             } else {
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/ep/.nvm/versions/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:24:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/ep/.nvm/versions/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:91:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/Users/ep/.nvm/versions/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:507:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/ep/.nvm/versions/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:260:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/ep/.nvm/versions/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:240:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/Users/ep/.nvm/versions/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:171:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/ep/.nvm/versions/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:153:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/ep/.nvm/versions/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:120:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprListItem (/Users/ep/.nvm/versions/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:966:16)
    at Parser.pp.parseCallExpressionArguments (/Users/ep/.nvm/versions/v5.0.0/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:336:20)
```

I can provide additional code snippets if that would help but the offending block is already included in the error message.  Thanks for any insight you can provide!

Comment: Please provide a link to the package you are using, there is none by that name, did you mean node-babel? I would start by using a non-deprecated/actively maintained package like `babel`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running version 6.x of babel, you need to use the babel react preset (as stated [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html)).

> If you are using babel 6.x, you will need to install the relevant preset/plugins. To get started, you can run `npm install -g babel babel-preset-react` and then run `babel --presets react --watch src/ --out-dir lib/`. For more information: check out the [babel 6 blog post](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/29/6.0.0/)

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly, missed that with the new version of babel.  Will be sure to post version information next time I ask a question like this.